# How to keep all my django applications in specific folder

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I have a Django project, let's say "project1". 
Typical folder structure for applications is:

```
/project1/
         /app1/
         /app2/
         ...
         __init__.py
         manage.py
         settings.py
         urls.py
```

What should I do if I want to hold all of my applications in some separate folder, 'apps' for example? So that structure should look like the following:

```
/project/
         apps/
              app1/
              app2/
              ...
         __init__.py
         manage.py
         settings.py
         urls.py
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can add your `apps` folder to your python path by inserting the following in your `settings.py`:

```
import os
import sys

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))
```

Then you can use all the apps in this folder just in the same way as they were in your project root!

Comment: If you ask me, this leads to confusion.

Comment: This leads to conflicts when running tests.

Comment: @ErnestJumbe What kind of conflicts when running tests? I use this methods and run tests fine.

Comment: Does this work with Django 3? I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages'` when I run the server. `pages` is the name of one of the apps.

Comment: For Django 3 this answer worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39747289/1365699

Answer (score 25):

You can do this very easily, but you need to change the `settings.py` to look like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'apps.app1',
    'apps.app2',
    # ...
)
```

And your `urls.py` to look like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    (r'^app1/',include('apps.app1')),    
    (r'^app2/',include('apps.app2')),    
)
```

.. and modify any `import`s to point to the app location

Comment: I recommend against using this method, as it might lead to other apps not being able to reference your own application, and will require you to change all imports in your apps to point to the new directory. I think the right way is in [Bernhard Vallant's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3948821/1057102).

Comment: This same pattern is followed in [django-oscar](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar) project.

Comment: I downvoted for the same reason as sleblanc - especially thinking about reusable models, where you might relate to a model using e.g. `ForeignKey('appname.ModelName', ...)` being upset by this

Comment: If you plan to use this convention in the mid of the development note that your migrations will create new tables in the database and won't map to the data you were working with.

Answer (score 21):

How about you utilize the `BASE_DIR` variable already present in the `settings.py`.

Just add the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps'))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Shouldn't `BASE_DIR` be un-quoted?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I'll edit the answer. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer for Django 3.

Answer (score 7):

As a slight variant to `Berhard Vallant`'s or `Anshuman`'s answers, here is an alternative snippet to place in `settings.py`

```py
import os
import sys  # Insert this line

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Insert the two lines below
APPS_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '<your_project_dir_name>/apps/')
sys.path.insert(0, APPS_DIR)
```

Doing it in this way has the added benefit that your template directories are cleaner as they will look like below. Without the `APPS_DIR` variable, there will be a lot of repitition of `<your_project_dir_name>/apps/` within the `DIRS` list of the `TEMPLATES` list.

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(APPS_DIR, '<app_name>/templates/<app_name>'),
            os.path.join(APPS_DIR, '<app_name>/templates/<app_name>'),
            ...
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

You can list the apps within the `INSTALLED_APPS` list as normal with either the short-form name given in `apps.py` or by using the long-form syntax of `appname.apps.AppnameConfig` replacing `appname` with your app's name.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy and simple you need to add to settings.py

```
import os
import sys

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))
```

and edit your app config for example

old app config:

```
    class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
          default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
          name = 'myapp'
```

to new app  config:

```
    class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
        default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
        label='myapp'
        name = 'apps.myapp'
```

than installed apps example:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     ...
     'apps.myapp.apps.MyappConfig'
     ...
]
```

I think it's very usefull and helpfull.Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper (which is a bit dated but still valid), you can use the included `add2virtualenv` command to augment your python path:

```
mkdir apps
cd apps
pwd
[/path/to/apps/dir]
```

Copy that path to clipboard, then:

```
add2virtualenv /path/to/apps/dir
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `__init__.py` (4 underscores in total) in your apps folder. Now you can just do

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('polls/',include('apps.polls.urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my project folder structure is the following:

```
/project/
   /apps/
      /app1/
      /app2/
   /src/
      /settings.py
      ...
```

So I've solved it with these two lines on my `settings.py`:

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../apps'))
```

No need to alter `urls.py`.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

This is the folder structure:

```
/project1
    /apps
        /myapp
```

inside apps.py under /myapp:

```
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "apps.myapp"
```

In the settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "apps.myapp.apps.MyAppConfig",
]
```