# How can I set subapps in django?

Tags: python, django

I have two apps under one project and decide to move these two apps under `apps` parent directory.
My current structure is,

```
project
  - app1 
  - app2
  - project
       - __init__.py
       - asgi.py
       - settings.py
       - urls.py
       - wsgi.py
```

New structure I am trying to have,

```
project
  - templates
  - static
  - apps
       - app1 
       - app2
  - project
       - __init__.py
       - asgi.py
       - settings.py
       - urls.py
       - wsgi.py
```

Following to this, [How to keep all my django applications in specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948356/how-to-keep-all-my-django-applications-in-specific-folder)
I edited my `settings.py`

```py
from os.path import abspath, basename, dirname, join
BASE_DIR = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file)))
PROJECT_ROOT = dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    'apps.app1.apps.App1Config',
    'apps.app2.apps.App2Config',
]
```

I got an error that 
`ModuleNOtFoundError: No module named 'app1'`
Where should I have to edit to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve this format

```
project
  - templates
  - static
  - apps
       - app1 
       - app2
  - project
       - __init__.py
       - asgi.py
       - settings.py
       - urls.py
       - wsgi.py
```

in the `settings.py`

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

and under `apps` folder create a new file `__init__.py`

and then back to `settings.py`, `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ... # other apps

    'apps.app1',
    'apps.app2',

]
```

you can check one my project that uses this kind of format in here https://github.com/michaelhenry/localizr

Comment: It worked. I had to figure out other files that import `app1` and `app2`.

Comment: @jayko03 happy to help :)