# Importing models from one project into another (gives RuntimeError)

Tags: python, django, django-models

How do I import certain models from one project in one directory, into another project in another directory? Both projects share the same database.

My directory structure is like this:

```
root
    directory1
        project1
        app1_of_project1
            models.py
        ...
        manage.py
    directory2
        project2
        app1_of_project2
            models.py
        ...
        manage.py
```

App1_of_project2 needs some models from app1_of_project1.

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3369581/), but I get:

```
RuntimeError: Model class app1_of_project1.models.Model1 doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

`INSTALLED_APPS` of project1 has app1_of_project1 included, and `INSTALLED_APPS` of project2 has app1_of_project2 included.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3115550/) gives me a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I cannot merge the two projects and make them separate apps within one project.

Also, I do not want to move the project directory to PYTHON_PATH.

Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do this without having both apps in the `INSTALLED_APPS` of each project. That is the only way Django can find the models for an app.

Comment: @solarissmoke how do you include an app of another project in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: The standard way is to create a reusable app. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/reusable-apps/